# Can a general binary sextic form be put into the following form?

Tags: nt.number-theory, invariant-theory

Let $F(x,y) = a_6 x^6 + a_5 x^5 y + \cdots + a_0 y^6$ be a binary sextic form with real coefficients and non-zero discriminant. Can one always find an element $U = \begin{pmatrix} u_1 & u_2 \\ u_3 & u_4 \end{pmatrix}$ in $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that the form

$$\displaystyle F_U(x,y) = F(u_1 x + u_2 y, u_3 x + u_4 y)$$

is of the shape

$$\displaystyle F_U(x,y) = A_6 x^6 + A_4 x^4 y^2 + A_2 x^2 y^4 + A_0 y^6?$$

If the answer is yes, can one give a criterion to decide whether $U$ can be chosen to have coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$, which is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ containing all coefficients of $F$?

Comment: In general it can't be done even over ${\bf C}$, because the roots of such a sextic are paired by some involution of ${\bf P}^1$, and this happens only in a hyperplane in the space of all binary sextics.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Is there any criterion which depends only on the coefficients of the sextic which determines whether such an involution exists?

Answer (score 2):

You may know this already, but, if not, the following may be helpful to you:

The ring of invariants for binary sextics is generated in degrees 2, 4, 6, 10, and 15. (See [this reference on binary sextics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_of_a_binary_form#Covariants_of_a_binary_sextic).)  Thus, in your notation (at least when the field $\mathbb{F}$ has characteristic $0$) for $k=2,4,6,10, 15$ there exists a polynomial $Q_k:S^6(\mathbb{F}^2)\to \mathbb{F}$ that is homogeneous of degree $k$ that satisfies 
$$
Q_k\bigl(F_U(x,y)\bigr) = \det(U)^{3k}\,Q_k\bigl(F(x,y)\bigr)\tag1
$$
for all $U\in\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{F})$, and, moreover, every polynomial $Q: S^6(\mathbb{F}^2)\to \mathbb{F}$ that satisfies
$$
Q\bigl(F_U(x,y)\bigr) = Q\bigl(F(x,y)\bigr)
$$
for all $U\in\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{F})$ is, in fact, a polynomial in $\{1,Q_2,Q_4,Q_6,Q_{10},Q_{15}\}$.  It is known that ${Q_{15}}^2$ is a polynomial in $\{Q_2,Q_4,Q_6,Q_{10}\}$ and that this is the only relation among these polynomials. Consequently, the polynomials $Q_{k}$ are irreducible.

Taking $U = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$, one sees that when $F(x,y)$ is in the desired form, one has $F_U(x,y) = F(x,y)$.  Conversely, $F(x,y)$ can be put into the desired form over the algebraic closure $\mathbb{F}^+$ of $\mathbb{F}$ if and only if there exists a $U\in\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{F}^+)$ satisfying $U^2 = I$ and $U\not=I$ such that $F_U(x,y) = F(x,y)$. Using (1) with $k=15$, one finds that the existence of such a $U$ for a given $F(x,y)$ implies
$$
Q_{15}\bigl(F(x,y)\bigr) = 0.
$$
Thus, the hypersurface $Q_{15}=0$ in $S^6(\mathbb{F})$ must be an irreducible component of the hypersurface $L\subset S^6(\mathbb{F})$ consisting of sextics that can be written in the desired form after a linear change of variables.

Meanwhile, it seems likely that $L$ is irreducible, since, over $\mathbb{F}^+$ anyway, we know, by Noam's observation/comment that it can be 'parametrized' by a connected algebraic variety.  Assuming this detail, it would follow that the necessary and sufficient condition for $F(x,y)$ to be written in the above form over $\mathbb{F}^+$ is that it lie in the zero locus of $Q_{15}$.  (I don't know how to tell when it can be done over $\mathbb{F}$, but perhaps this can be deduced by knowing something about the values $Q_k\bigl(F(x,y)\bigr)$ for $k=2,4,6,10$.)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done only if the corresponding genus 2 curve has an extra involution. That is equivalent with  $\chi_{35}=0$ or $J_{30}=0$, both $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ invariants given in terms of the coefficients of the sextic.  In such case, the curve is defined over its field of moduli.

Answer (score 0):

There is an old method of Clebsch called typical representation which shows how to write a sextic in canonical form with coefficients $A$ given by invariants. I did not look at it in detail but my colleague Llyod West did in his recent work ["The Moduli Space of Cubic Rational Maps"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3247). See in particular the reference therein
to the paper by Mestre.